# What does nil mean in golang?

Tags: go

There are many cases using **nil** in golang. For example:

```
func (u *URL) Parse(ref string) (*URL, error) {
    refurl, err := Parse(ref)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return u.ResolveReference(refurl), nil
}
```

but we can't use it like this:

```
var str string //or var str int
str = nil
```

the golang compiler will throw a `can't use nil as type string in assignment` error.

Looks like `nil` can only be used for a pointer of struct and interface. If that is the case, then **what does it mean?**
and **when we use it to compare to the other object, how do they compare, in other words, how does golang determine one object is nil**?

**EDIT:For example, if an interface is nil, its type and value must be nil at the same time. How does golang do this?**

Comment: You'll have to understand Go types and the different values an object of each type may have. All details about which things are nil, assignable to nil, comparable to nil and so an are explained in https://golang.org/ref/spec which is short enough to read in one go and clear enough to understand it.

Comment: Empty string in Go is "". To test if a string has value, simply do `str == ""`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynoY2xz-F8s

Answer (score 178, accepted):

In Go, `nil` is the **zero value for pointers, interfaces, maps, slices, channels and function types**, representing an *uninitialized* value.

`nil` doesn't mean some "undefined" state, it's a proper value in itself. An object in Go is `nil` simply if and only if it's value is `nil`, which it can only be if it's of one of the aforementioned types.

An `error` is an interface, so `nil` is a valid value for one, unlike for a `string`. For obvious reasons a `nil` error represents *no error*.

Comment: See spec here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables

Comment: I find the design around this to be silly. I'm working on a project where I need to return a nil and setting pointers to nil. But when checking against `nil`, my test fails because the type gets erased. Why couldn't they just make nil or null be null and not point to anything?

Answer (score 9):

`nil` in Go is simply the `NULL` pointer value of other languages.

You can effectively use it in place of any pointer or interface (interfaces are somewhat pointers).

You can use it as an error, because the [error type is an interface](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error).

You can't use it as a string because in Go, a string is a value.

`nil` is untyped in Go, meaning you can't do that:

```
var n = nil
```

Because here you lack a type for `n`. However, you can do

```
var n *Foo = nil
```

Note that `nil` being the zero value of pointers and interfaces, uninitialized pointers and interfaces will be `nil`.

Comment: Wrong: `nil` has no type. It isn't typed. You can't do: `var n = nil` not because nil has a type, it's because, the compiler can't derive what will be the type of `n`, it can't defer the type, because, `nil` has no type.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, so long after the answer. An edit would have been more _a propos_. But thanks nonetheless.

Comment: Additional example: `func getStuff() string { return nil }` won't compile with message `cannot use nil as type string in return argument`. In java `public String getStuff() { return null; }` works perfectly fine. Not sure what you meant by "string is a value" - string is a slice of bytes.

Comment: A `string` is a value by opposition to a pointer (or an `error` which is an interface, essentially a pointer). Maybe the term _concrete type_ would be more precise, but I don't think it would be more understandable for a beginner.

Answer (score 5):

***nil*** is also a value but only difference is- it is empty.

In Javascript for the un-initialized variable will be ***undefined***. In the same way Golang has ***nil*** as default value for all the un-initalized data types.

Answer (score 2):

*nil* in Go means a zero value for **pointers**, **interfaces, maps, slices, and channels**.
It means the value is uninitialized

Answer (score 1):

- For the data types like slice and pointers which "refer" to other types, "nil" indicates that the variable does not refer to an instance (equivalent of null pointer in other languages)
- It is thee zero value of the variables of type functions, maps, interfaces, channels and structures

Answer (score 1):

`nil` is a predeclared identifier in Go that represents **zero values** for **pointers, interfaces, channels, maps, slices and function types.**
`nil` being the zero value of pointers and interfaces, uninitialized pointers and interfaces will be nil.

In Go, string can’t be `nil`. A string doesn’t qualify to be assigned `nil`.

```
a := nil   // It will throw an error 'use of untyped nil'

var a *int = nil  //It will work
```

Comment: Typo in your code? See https://play.golang.org/p/G3a2aqgjcnj.

Answer (score 1):

In Go `nil` is predeclared identifier that represents nothing for pointers, interfaces, channels, maps, slices and function types. Uninitialized pointers and interfaces will be `nil`. A string doesn’t qualify to be either of the above-mentioned types and hence can’t be assigned `nil`.
If you declare a variable by shorthand decleration like this: `variable:=nil` this will give compile time error because compiler has no idea which type it has to assign to `variable` .

In Go map, slice and function doesn't support comparison but can be compared with `nil`.
If any two map, slice or function are assigned to `nil` and compared with each other then it will raise runtime error.
But if we assign `nil` to any two pointer variables and compare them with each other then no error will occur.

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

 func main() {
    var i *int =nil
    var j *int =nil
    if i==j {
      fmt.Println("equal")
    } else {
      fmt.Println("no")
    }
}
```

This code works fine and prints output as `equal`.

Answer (score 0):

In Golang, datatype can use nil is pointers, interfaces, maps, slices, channels, function types and errors

in **String** value is ""

in **INT** value is **ZERO**

Comment: In any other programming language `""` is a valid string. But Google had to be weird about it :/

Answer (score 0):

In **Golang**, `zero value` is the **default value** for defined variables. The default value of different datatypes are:

- `0` for integer types
- `0.0` for floating types
- `false` for boolean types
- `""` for string types
- `nil` for interfaces, slices, channels, maps, pointers and functions

So, `nil` is the zero value or default value for interfaces, slices, channels, maps, pointers and functions.

For example,

```golang
var a int
var s []int
var s1 []int = []int{1, 2}

fmt.Println(a == nil) // throw error
// invalid operation: a == nil (mismatched types int and untyped nil)

fmt.Println(s == nil) // true
fmt.Println(s1 == nil) // false
```

Since `error` is an interface, we can write

```golang
_, err := Parse("")
if err != nil { // if there is an error
  // handle error
}
```