# Why `fmt.Println("%T\n", e)` where `e` is an error variable prints out <nil> and not its type?

Tags: go

I was recently playing with the Go language and I bumped into something a bit weird to say the least, let's consider a very simple function:

```
func main() {
    n, e := fmt.Println(`He said: "Hello"`)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", n)
}
```

Which outputs what I was expecting:

```
He said: "Hello"
int
```

Now if I want to display the type of `e`:

```
func main() {
    n, e := fmt.Println(`He said: "Hello"`)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", e)
}
```

and this time prints out:

```
He said: "Hello"
<nil>
```

I get the part that there is no error so `e` is an empty pointer: [`nil`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983118/what-does-nil-mean-in-golang) but I would have not expected to be a ~~type~~ on its own.

Why am I not getting the actual type?

If so, is there a workaround? (not saying my use case is a realistic one but curious if there is any possibility)

Comment: In case of `error` you will receive real type, but in case of `no-error` the type is `nil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Errors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Errors)
>
> The predeclared type error is defined as
>
> ```
> type error interface {
>   Error() string
> }
> ```
>
> It is the conventional interface for representing an error condition,
>   with the nil value representing no error.
>
> [Interface types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)
>
> An interface type specifies a method set called its interface. A
>   variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method
>   set that is any superset of the interface. Such a type is said to
>   implement the interface. The value of an uninitialized variable of
>   interface type is nil.
>
> [The zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)
>
> When storage is allocated for a variable, either through a declaration
>   or a call of new, or when a new value is created, either through a
>   composite literal or a call of make, and no explicit initialization is
>   provided, the variable or value is given a default value. Each element
>   of such a variable or value is set to the zero value for its type: nil
>   for interfaces.

---

A zero-value `error` type, an interface, has no type.Its value is `nil`.

Comment: I see makes sense about why Printf cannot resolve any kind of type. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> `e` is an empty pointer

Nope, `error` itself - interface, so you won't have type here.